# How to modify a group to be non system group in Linux

Tags: linux

I have added a group as a system group. Using a command `groupadd -r` . I have couple of users also assigned to this group.

Now I want to change thuis group to Non-System group..or say normal group.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: I think in order to avoid these problems in future you should use more flexible solutions for user management than CLI. For instance, look to the FreeIPA...

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to remove the group ID and recreate it with a non-system permission, but with the same GID. Assuming the group name as `suroot`, use the following commands:

```
id=`cat /etc/group | grep suroot | sed -r 's/:/\ /g' | awk '{print $3}'`
groupdel suroot
groupadd suroot -g $id
```

EDIT: this assumes a RedHat-like linux distribution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I cant delete the group as it is been assigned to couple of users. So requirement is just to make it non system group. :) Thanks.

Comment: It works! You can safely remove/recreate a group. It does not affect the users of that group. They just stay with an undefined group ID for 1 second :-)

Comment: But I have this group as a primary group for user. So i need to do this cascade delete for user and then the group and then adding back everything again. The major ask here is, a system groups have an id less than 500. And for Normal group it is more than 500. I need it to be more than 500 bcoz of some business logic. And I cant hard code this id and it may raise a conflict.